# Why just one of the forms is sent?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have these two forms, and I want to send them both with one click. The first form loads up an image into the server. The second one loads up infomation into a database. For some reason always just the "myform" is sent. Any ideas?

```
<form action="uploadpic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-  data" />
    <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />
</form>

<form method = "post" id= "myform" name="myform" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF  ?>">
    <table width = "400" border = "0" cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "2">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#add").click(function () {

           var $form1 = $("#myform");

           $.post($form1.attr("action"), $form1.serialize(), function () {
               alert('Form 1 elküldve');
           });

           $('form[name="user_image"]').each(function () {

               var $form = $(this);

               $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function () {
                   alert('Form 2 elküldve');
               });
           })
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: did you close off the second form? doesn't look like it.

Comment: Why you don't do it with one form only? btw. as Fred said... you didnt close the second... and in my opionion you haven't done anything with the second at all.. complety useless code?

Comment: *...preeeetty mooch.*

Comment: You don't select the first form with $('form[name="user_image"]'). It doesn't have attribute name="user_image"

Comment: Yes i closed it, just pasted it badly :S I tried to insert form into form, but it doesn't load up the picture that way. I don't get it.

Comment: Nesting form into form will not work. Every form must be separate.

Answer (score 1):

you can equally use one form and send both data where you want them

```
<form action="uploadpic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-  data" />
   <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />

          <table width = "400" border = "0" cellspacing = "1" 
             cellpadding = "2">
//... other form details
</form>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#add").click(function () {
   var $form1 = $("#myform");
   $.post($form1.attr("action"), $form1.serialize(), function () {
    alert('Form 1 elküldve');
   });

   $('form[name="user_image"]').each(function () {
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function () {
        alert('Form 2 elküldve');
    });
   })
  });
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your javascript a little.
`$('input[name="user_image"]').each(function () {` will iterate over inputs with `name="user_image"` and get its form. (I suppose this is what you are trying for)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#add").click(function () {

       var $form1 = $("#myform");

       $.post($form1.attr("action"), $form1.serialize(), function () {
           alert('Form 1 elküldve');
       });

       $('input[name="user_image"]').each(function () {

           var $form = $(this).parent('form');

           $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function () {
               alert('Form 2 elküldve');
           });
       })
  });
});
</script>
```

**BUT** if you have only one input element with `name="user_image"` then this is more appropriate:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#add").click(function () {

       var $form1 = $("#myform");

       $.post($form1.attr("action"), $form1.serialize(), function () {
           alert('Form 1 elküldve');
       });

       var $form = $('input[name="user_image"]').parent('form');

       $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function () {
           alert('Form 2 elküldve');
       });
  });
});
</script>
```